# In Foundry Workshop, is it possible to reset a scenario when a user navigates away from a Workshop tab?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios, foundry-workshop

I've created a scenario in Foundry Workshop, and would like to set it up so that it resets whenever a user changes their active Workshop tab. Is it possible to accomplish this within scenario variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scenario array variable is produced from a scenario object set, then changing the object set should reset it. See the relevant documentation for this at https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/scenarios-save/ .

If you have a single dynamic scenario that you'd like to reset, then you can use the "Reset variable" event to reset it to its default value.